# executing task in a user defined time interval using work manager

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I have a use case, in which I take input from the user of a time interval. For example, the user chooses 10 pm to 4 am. During this time interval, I want to basically track the screen time of the phone using `Intent.Action_Screen_On` and `Intent.Action_Screen_OFF`.

How do I approach this problem of taking time interval as input from the user and creating a work manager task which runs in the background during that interval?

Answer (score 0):

This is not what WorkManager is used for. The idea of it is to be used for "persistent work". You give some criteria - constraints that need to be satisfied for the work to be executed and at the right time, based on your constraints(explicit) and the implicit one from the system(based on power management, doze, power buckets, etc) the work will start and some point, the system will ensure that it will finish successfully throughout device restarts, etc.

If you are actively tracking user interactions - you need to use a Service.

Please note that I am not familiar with how exactly Intent.Action_Screen_On and Intent.Action_Screen_OFF works, but I can assure you that WM is not your choice and there is no way for you to incorporate them.